# Unable to implement Dijkstra's Algorithm using OpenMP in C

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I am trying to parallelize Dijkstra using OpenMP, but the program is not working correctly. Sometimes the correct results are displayed while other times I get wrong values, I assume this is because multiple threads are updating the same variable. However I cannot find the source of this problem because I am making shared variable updates inside critical regions. Can someone please help me identify what mistake am I making my assignment is due soon and is this code conceptually correct?

```
int minDistance(int s,int e,int dist[], bool sptSet[])
{
    // Initialize min value
    int mini = INT_MAX, min_index;

    for (int v = s; v <= e; v++){
        if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] < mini){
            mini = dist[v];
    
            min_index = v;
        }
        //printf("min_ind %d\n",min_index);
    }
    return min_index;
}

void Update(int graph[V][V],int s,int e,int hold,int dist[], bool sptSet[]){

    for (int v = s; v <= e; v++){

        // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet,
        // there is an edge from u to v, and total
        // weight of path from src to  v through u is
        // smaller than current value of dist[v]
        if (!sptSet[v] && graph[hold][v] && dist[hold] != INT_MAX && dist[hold] + graph[hold][v] < dist[v]){
                
            dist[v] = dist[hold] + graph[hold][v];
        }
    }
}
```

```
void dijkstra(int graph[V][V],int src)
{
    int dist[V]; // The output array.  dist[i] will hold the
                 // shortest
    // distance from src to i
    
    bool sptSet[V]; // sptSet[i] will be true if vertex i is
                    // included in shortest
    // path tree or shortest distance from src to i is
    // finalized
 
    // Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as
    // false

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;
 
    // Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0
    dist[src] = 0;
    int min;
    int hold;
    int u;

    // Find shortest path for all vertices
    float start = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel shared(hold) private(u) num_threads(3)
    {
        min=INT_MAX;
        int x = omp_get_num_threads();
   
        int chunk = V/x;

        int me = omp_get_thread_num();

        int startv = me * chunk; 
        int endv = startv + chunk - 1;
        int count = 0;

        for (count = 0; count < V - 1; count++) {
            // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of
            // vertices not yet processed. u is always equal to
            // src in the first iteration.

            u = minDistance(startv,endv,dist, sptSet);

            //updating overall minimum
#pragma omp critical
            {
                if(min > dist[u]){
                    min = dist[u];
                    hold = u;
                }
            }
            //waiting for all threads to execute critical section bfr proceeding
    #pragma omp barrier
            // Mark the picked vertex as processed
    
        #pragma omp single
            {
                sptSet[hold] = true;
            }
    #pragma omp barrier

            // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the
            // picked vertex.
            Update(graph,startv,endv,hold,dist,sptSet);

            min = INT_MAX;
        }
    }

    float end = omp_get_wtime();
    // print the constructed distance array
    printSolution(dist);
    printf("Running time: %f ms\n", (end - start)*1000);
}
```

----------------THE SERIAL CODE:--------------------

```
int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[])
{
    // Initialize min value
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index;
     
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
            min = dist[v], min_index = v;
     
    return min_index;
}
     
// A utility function to print the constructed distance
// array
void printSolution(int dist[])
{
    printf("Vertex \t\t Distance from Source\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        printf("%d \t\t\t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
}
     
// Function that implements Dijkstra's single source
// shortest path algorithm for a graph represented using
// adjacency matrix representation
void dijkstra(int graph[V][V], int src)
{
    int dist[V]; // The output array.  dist[i] will hold the
                 // shortest
        // distance from src to i
     
    bool sptSet[V]; // sptSet[i] will be true if vertex i is
                    // included in shortest
    // path tree or shortest distance from src to i is
    // finalized
     
    // Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as
    // false
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;
     
    // Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0
    dist[src] = 0;
     
    // Find shortest path for all vertices
    for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++) {
        // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of
        // vertices not yet processed. u is always equal to
        // src in the first iteration.
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
     
        // Mark the picked vertex as processed
        sptSet[u] = true;
     
        // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the
        // picked vertex.
        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        {
            // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet,
            // there is an edge from u to v, and total
            // weight of path from src to  v through u is
            // smaller than current value of dist[v]
            if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v]
                && dist[u] != INT_MAX
                && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
        }
    }
     
    // print the constructed distance array
    printSolution(dist);
}
```

Comment: I assume you are busy properly formatting your code, and within the next few minutes there will be one more edit in which the code will be formatted. We will all wait for this to happen before we look at the code.

Comment: @MikeNakis Sorry sir, I forgot to add some lines while copying it.

Comment: Your parallel code contains unnecessary barriers and a critical section.  Can you show us a properly working serial code (i.e a [mre])? So, we can show you how to parallelize it.

Comment: @Laci I have attached the serial code

Comment: @MikeNakis should be formatted ok now

Comment: You should parallelize the `for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)` loop in the `minDistance` function using a user-defined reduction. Is this the bottleneck?

Comment: What is  the result of the following expression if `u==v` ? `(!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])` Is it always false?

Comment: It appears that the value of your "V" variable must be magically chosen to be a multiple of whatever happens to be returned by `omp_get_num_threads()`, or else your calculation of `chunk` will be incorrect, thus leading to threads overwriting the data produced by other threads. Even if `omp_get_num_threads()` is guaranteed to return `3` because of `num_threads(3)`, it is best not to tempt your fate: make `num_threads` be a function of V. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: So, it means that `graph[u][u]` is always false?

Comment: @Laci its false because I loops have been ignored.

Comment: @Laci yes always false

Comment: @MikeNakis it does't solve the problem because I have made sure that the number of vertices are exactly divisible by the num_threads

Comment: OK, it this case just put a `#pragma omp parallel for` before `for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)` in `dijkstra` (in the serial code). You can also consider parallelize the for loop in `minDistance`, but that requires a user-defined reduction.

Comment: I must be missing something, because it seems so obvious that if it was a problem then others would have seen it too by now, but doesn't the call to `Update()` need to also be guarded with `#pragma omp`?

Comment: @Laci The task I have is to extract the best possible time results,, #pragma omp parallel for doesnt solve this problem when tested on a graph of 2000 vertices. I also have to consider the possibility of false sharing etc

Comment: @MikeNakis I don't thinkso because each thread will only update its part of the chunk

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Without this, it is hard tell how to make it faster.

Comment: @Laci the serial code i have attached is the simplest version i have

Comment: OK, but if I copy it to https://godbolt.org/ I cannot compile it. Can you make it a whole code?

Comment: @Laci sure the working code is given here :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's algorithm is a good example of an algorithm where the standard formulation is very hard to parallelize. Every step of 1. finding the minimum 2. updating its neighbors depends on the previous. Therefore the best you can do is 1. making that minimum into an OpenMP reduction 2. making the update into a parallel loop. On graphs with small degree this will not give you much speedup. It also means taht your code is not correct: you are trying to parallelize over the outer steps, which are sequential.

However, you don't have to update only the neighbors of that minimum point: you can update all points in every step. That simplifies the code, and reduces overhead. It also does more work, but in wall clock time it may finish slightly faster.